# Can't get the right variable to define the cell loaded in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview with two types of tableviewcells

A) Title/Type with two labels

B) A tableviewcell with a collection view running horizontally

The tableview cells alternate, starting with A as index 0, followed by B as index 1, etc.

The problem I run into is that for all B cells, I am looking to pass a variable to it in order to define its contents.

Here is my code:

```
//Here I am defining two variables that are inherent in all of the cells
struct dealType {
var title: String?
var type: String?
 }

class ViewController:


//Here I create an array of deals based off above

//deal Type
var dealTypeArray: [dealType] =
//A
[dealType(title: "A", type: "A1"),
dealType(title: "A", type: "A1"),
//B
dealType(title: "B", type: "B1"),
dealType(title: "B", type: "B1"),
//C
dealType(title: "C", type: "C1"),
dealType(title: "C", type: "C1"),
//D
dealType(title: "D", type: "D1"),
dealType(title: "D", type: "D1")
]

    //TableView Functionality - here is the alternate view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //if even, display A
    if indexPath.row.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "A", for: indexPath) as! ATableViewCell
        cell.typeLabel.text = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].type!
        cell.titleLabel.text = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].title!
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    } else {
        //Return B
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "B", for: indexPath) as! BTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

         //The current solution that doesn't work - this tells the cell what to look at
        cell.typeSelected = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].title!
        return cell
    }
    
}

 //Here is my collectionViewCell B within the TableViewCell B

  class BCollectionViewCell:

  // I have variable typeSelected that I am using to define the collectionView data
  var typeSelected = String()

  // I have a function that looks up to this using the typeSelected
   
func getDeals(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Deal")
    //The query is based off of typeSelected
    query.whereKey("DealType", equalTo: typeSelected)


    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
          //Get Data

            }
        completionHandler()
        print(self.dealArray)
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is that typeSelected when the query is run shows "" as opposed to the title that was defined in the view controller's array.

Comment: Quick google search for `swift uitableviewcell with uicollectionview` returns lots of examples, articles, discussions, etc.

Comment: are you sure it's a collection view? try a simpler solution first, see if you can just display text in a simple cell.

Answer (score 0):

I used setSelected and created a boolean to check if it's set. The problem was that initially the cell was loaded before typeSelected was taken into account.

```
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    //Write Function To Get Deals
    if loaded == false {
        getDeals {
            self.dealCollectionView.reloadData()
            self.dealCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.loaded = true
            }
    }
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```